# Repository bugzilla package changed to bugzilla3 in Lenny - is it upgradable?

Tags: debian, debian-lenny, bugzilla, debian-etch, upgrade

[This question](http://www.debianhelp.org/node/15239) was asked in [debianhelp.org](http://debianhelp.org/) almost half a year ago, but never got an answer. I wasn't the one who posted it, however I was today facing exactly the same question:

> Hello all! We are using a Bugzilla
>   server install on a Debian 4/Etch
>   server and are starting to look at the
>   upgrade to Debian 5/Lenny. I was
>   hoping to upgrade the existing
>   Bugzilla server and database from the
>   oldstable (v2.22) to the newer stable
>   in Lenny (v3) when we get to doing a
>   dist-upgrade. However from testing in
>   a virtual machine it seems that the
>   old package was called "Bugzilla"
>   whereas the Lenny package is called
>   "Bugzilla3" and I could not figure a
>   way to directly upgrade between the
>   two.
>
> Is it possible to establish some kind
>   of upgrade path quickly after the
>   dist-upgrade to minimise downtime
>   using apt-get or aptitude? Going on
>   past experiences I would not want to
>   do a fresh install with the Bugzilla3
>   package and attempt to inject the old
>   database into it (previous attempts
>   failed miserably!) :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert on debian, but to get you started I'd suggest the following:

1. Mimic your current environment on a virtual machine. [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org) comes to mind. Then plan and exercise the upgrade there. It should be enough to dump your life database, restore it on the virtual machine and copy over the bugzilla setup (you might have to edit the `localconfig` file.
2. I think it is an advantage that the new package is called bugzilla3. This might help you in installing it parallel to the existing one and then follow chapter 2.7.3 of [the documentation](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.4/en/html/upgrade.html).
3. Before you do anything. Backup. Backup. Backup.

In my experience, upgrading bugzilla with the `./checksetup.pl` script is really painless.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the documentation in /usr/share/doc/bugzilla3 . Usually Debian-packages have upgrade instructions in a file called NEWS